# text-align on kendo-grid-column in angular2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-ui-grid

How do I align text to the right on a

`<kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid-column>`

because both

`<kendo-grid-column field="margin" title="Margin" style="text-align: right;">
</kendo-grid-column>`

and

`<kendo-grid-column field="margin" title="Margin" text-align="right">
</kendo-grid-column>`

dont work. Please could someone help?

Answer (score 12):

This one should be work

```
.k-header .k-link{
   text-align: right;
}
```

you can use this one also for specific one

```
[headerStyle]="{'text-align': 'right'}"
[style]="{'text-align': 'right'}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it with a template:

```
 <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
   <span class="right-align">{{dataItem.ProductName}}</span>
 </template>
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jL4VkZjYhoW2cXVQOdwu?p=preview)

Comment: It doesn't work. It removes my formatting then just displays it on the left

Comment: did you see the plunkr?

Comment: yes, i can get that to work but when i copy the code and change it accordingly, it doesnt work

Comment: make sure that you are copying the styles as well. Also you can inspect the element and see if the right-align class is there.

Comment: It has the class and style sheet it needs. I checked the element and it applies the right align but doesn't right align the text.

I just applied another style, color: aquamarine;, and that works fine

Comment: span is inline element in it does not take all the available space in the cell. Use block element or set span from inline to block
`<span style="text-align: right; display: block">{{dataItem.ProductName}}</span>`